# Python How to I check if last element has been reached in iterator tool chain?

Tags: python

```
for elt in itertools.chain.from_iterable(node):

if elt is the last element:
  do statement
```

How do I achieve this

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When the loop ends, the `elt` variable doesn't go out of scope, and still holds the last value given to it by the loop. So you could just put the code at the end of the loop and operate on the `elt` variable. It's not terribly pretty, but Python's scoping rules aren't pretty either.

The only problem with this (thanks, cvondrick) is that the loop might never execute, which would mean that `elt` doesn't exist - we'd get a `NameError`. So the full way to do it would be roughly:

```
del elt # not necessary if we haven't use elt before, but just in case
for elt in itertools.chain.from_iterable(node):
    do_stuff_to_each(elt)
try:
    do_stuff_to_last(elt)
except NameError: # no last elt to do stuff to
    pass
```

Comment: Just be careful in the case when the loop never executes as this could lead to some wild execution path.

Comment: Just drop the code to apply to the last element in the `else` clause.

Comment: @Ignacio - `for x in (): print x else: print x` gives a `NameError`. We need to catch the exception to cover the case where it never executes. (And putting it in an `else` wouldn't execute if we broke out of the loop. Which we might want to do.)

Answer (score 25):

You can do this by manually advancing the iterator in a while loop using `iter.next()`, then catching the `StopIteration` exception:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> it = chain([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])
>>> while True:
...     try:
...         elem = it.next()
...     except StopIteration:
...         print "Last element was:", elem, "... do something special now"
...         break
...     print "Got element:", elem
...     
... 
Got element: 1
Got element: 2
Got element: 3
Got element: 4
Got element: 5
Got element: 6
Got element: 7
Got element: 8
Got element: 9
Last element was: 9 ... do something special now
>>>
```

Comment: This is the way to do it for a more general solution (i.e. last two, last three, etc.) but for the last element, my solution is (IMHO) cleaner.

Comment: Your solution has less code, but IMO it's less explicit since it relies on a non-obvious scoping rule. I prefer the more explicit approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can't per se. You'd need to store the current item, advance the iterator, and catch the `StopIteration` exception. And then you'd need to somehow signal that you have the last item.

Comment: This wouldn't be hard to do, and is a more general solution, but isn't entirely necessary for the current task.

Answer (score 2):

I do something like this:

```
rng = len(mlist)
for i in range(rng):
    foo = mlist[i]
    foo.do_something_for_every_item_regardless()
    if i == rng - 1: #since we go from 0 to rng-1
        foo.last_item_only_operation()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    try:
      print(next(myIterator))
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a utility function that works like `enumerate()` except returns a bool if this was the last element.

Now you don't have to add any additional lines, and this works on iterables besides  lists.

```py
def endify(itr):
    '''
    Like enumerate() except returns a bool if this is the last item instead of the number
    '''
    itr = iter(itr)
    has_item = False
    ended = False
    next_item = None
    while not ended:
        try:
            next_item = next(itr)
        except StopIteration:
            ended = True
        if has_item:
            yield ended, item
        has_item = True
        item = next_item
```

Look how clean this can be used now:

```py
for end, i in endify(range(3)):
    print(f'Item: {i}, End: {end}')
```

```
Item: 0, End: False
Item: 1, End: False
Item: 2, End: True
```